# Trying to export schema from Hana Studios in a linux script using hdbsql commands

Tags: shell, syntax, export, hana

I am trying to write a script in linux that will back up a database from Hana Studio. I will be combining it into a bigger code, but at the moment I am breaking it into small parts to test it, and my problem involves just the small part where I try to actually export the schema. I used vi text editor in linux to make the script, and hdbsql commands to connect to Hana and run the export. No matter what I try, I keep getting a syntax error.

Here is an example of the line of hdbsql commands that I was trying to use:

```
$HDB_HOME/hdbsql -n $HANA_HOST:$HANA_PORT -i $HANA_DATABASE -u $HANA_USER -p $HANA_PASSWORD -B -c "EXPORT SCHEMA $EXPORT_SCHEMA AS BINARY INTO '$EXPORT_FOLDER';"
```

It has variables that were defined earlier in the code, but it seemed to read them fine. I also did try to skip the variables and input the required info directly into the hdbsql commands and it gave the same error. and without the export command it brings me to the "SAP HANA Database interactive terminal", so I am quite sure I am connecting successfully and that my error is coming from the export command.

the error reads:

```
* 257: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "SBOCOMMON": line 1 col 15 (at pos 15) SQLSTATE: HY000
```

I found [SAP's own Help Portal](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20da0bec751910148e69c9668ea3ccb8.html?version=2.0.06#examples) where they explain how to use the EXPORT command and it gave an example of:

```
EXPORT a."*", b."*" AS CSV INTO '/tmp' WITH REPLACE;
```

so I changed my code to match it with this:

```
EXPORT SBOCOMMON."*" AS BINARY INTO '/home/manualbackups/testbackup';
```

and I was shocked to still get the same error about incorrect syntax.

I found another source that shows how to do exactly what I am trying to do. [Link for reference, but it required a free account to view the whole code](https://www.sap-business-one-tips.com/how-to-make-your-own-schema-backup-script-in-hana/)
So I followed their steps, including using notepad++ instead of vi to make the script. my new line of hdbsql commands, including a new environment variable key they had me create for the credentials, looks like this:

```
./hdbsql -U DBBACKUP “EXPORT ${SCHEMA_NAME}.\”*\” AS BINARY INTO ‘${BACKUP_FULL_PATH}/’ WITH REPLACE THREADS 8″
```

and still the same error.

```
* 257: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "“EXPORT": line 1 col 1 (at pos 1) SQLSTATE: HY000
```

I am at a loss. I tried asking AI, I tried copy and pasting straight from SAP's Help Portal. And I tried copy and pasting straight from this other website that tries to show me how to do exactly what I want to do. Only changing the required variables such as host and password and such. And yet every time my syntax is somehow incorrect. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried running the commands without any variable replacements in a SQL Editor, e.g. HANA Studio or DBeaver? It appears to me that the problem here is the complexity of variable and string expansion by the SHELL when running the command. For example in the last command it looks like there are "fancy" quotation marks, instead of straight ones `\”*\”` instead of `\"*\"` .

Comment: Thank you, you were absolutely correct. I am not sure where or how I picked up the weird quotes, it must have been copy and pasting from somewhere, but I went into vi and deleted them and manually typed new ones and it worked finally. I appreciate the help.